# Can you 'print' a numpy array as a mesh?

Tags: mesh, scripting

Is there a way to 'print' a numpy array as a mesh?  For example say I have a numpy array of ones and zeros of shape `(10, 10, 10)` and the ones in the array would be the vertexes of the mesh while the python code creates the shapes for the mesh.  The shape of the array could be a theoretical cube domain and the indexes of the array could correspond with a certain point in the domain.  The code would then create the shapes for the mesh.

Comment: Are you familiar with dupliverts?

Comment: @batFINGER no what are they?